# What's the functional design pattern for a discriminated union with protected creation, and public read access?

Tags: design-patterns, f#, abstract-data-type, discriminated-union

Discriminated unions are typically used as data holders and give information on what they're holding, but occasionally I find myself having the need to prevent creation of a discriminated union, but to still be able to pattern match over it using familiar syntax.

For the sake of argument, let's say we represent a URI with a string, but I want to create a type that has a guaranteed validated URI (i.e., it's valid per the RFC), which is also a string. Just using Some/None doesn't work here, as I still want to access any invalid string as well. Also, I like a mild refactoring experience over the current codebase (replacing an existing single-case union with a new single-case union over many lines of code is much easier than with a multi-case union).

I can solve this problem as follows, which I think shows what I intend to do (leaving out the error cases for simplicity):

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module VerifiedUriModule =
    module VerifiedUri =
        type VerifiedUri = 
            private 
            | VerifiedUri of string

        let create uri = VerifiedUri uri  // validation and error cases go here

        let tryCreate uri = Some <| VerifiedUri uri  // or here

        let get (VerifiedUri uri) = uri

    let (|VerifiedUri|) x =
        VerifiedUri.get x
```

The extra level with the `AutoOpen` is simply to allow unqualified access of using the active recognizer.

I may end up using a typical `Result` type, but I was wondering whether this is a typical coding practice, or whether whenever I find myself doing something like this, I should hear a voice in my head saying "rollback, rollback!", because I'm violating classical functional programming principles (am I?).

I realize this is a case of information hiding and it looks much like mimicking OO class behaviors with data. What would be the typical F#'ish approach be (apart from creating a class with a private ctor)?

---

EDIT 2019-12-10: this issue [is now being discussed for inclusion in F#](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/810) as a language feature. Vote it up if you think it should be in:).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a fairly general sense, I think that the pattern you are describing is *abstract data type* - this is not a name for the specific F# implementation, but it fitst your description quite well.

To quote [Programming with Abstract Data Types](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.136.3043&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Barbara Liskov and Stephen Zilles in 1974:

> An 
>   abstract 
>   data 
>   type 
>   defines 
>   a 
>   class 
>   of 
>   abstract 
>   objects 
>   which 
>   is 
>   completely 
>   characterized 
>   by 
>   the 
>   operations 
>   available 
>   on 
>   those 
>   objects. 
>   This 
>   means 
>   that 
>   an 
>   abstract 
>   data 
>   type 
>   can 
>   be 
>   defined 
>   by 
>   defining 
>   the 
>   characterizing 
>   operations 
>   for 
>   that 
>   type.

In your example, you are defining an abstract data type `VerifiedUrl` which is described by three operations. The operations `create` (or `tryCreate`) create a a value of the abstract data type and the operation `get` allows you to get the value. The operations that create the value also capture the fact that you can only create a `VerifiedUrl` from a valid URL string.

This pattern is perhaps somewhat more focused on the fact that you are hiding the implementation details and exposing only certain operations for manipulating it - while in your case, another important fact is that the values of the abstract data type satisfy certain properties - but you could view those as invariants about the abstract data type. I cannot think of a better established concept to capture this idea.

Comment: Interesting quote! I didn't realise per se that this was what I was doing, but as you describe it, this concept makes sense. As an aside, you'd agree with capturing an abstract data type somewhat like I showed, or would you prefer an alternative approach in F#? I was thinking of abstracting away the specifics by creating a `Verified` DU where the 'create' and 'tryCreate' take a function that creates the inner, generalised value. This would make it wider applicable to any data type that has these properties (here: verifiability)

Comment: And would you say that this is a common programming pattern in functional languages? So far, I have worked mostly without this (using ubiquitous `option` and `result` instead), but I can surely pinpoint several places in my codebase where this can be useful.

Comment: @Abel, well, there are lenses (check out Haskell's implelementation), based on the Yoneda lemma from the Category Theory, it was designed specifically for such "hiding" purposes.. but.. it is much more common to avoid it and keep things much simplier.

Comment: @Abel - I think that what you have is quite a nice and generally useful. I suspect that doing something like generic `Verified<'T>` migth be tricky, because the checking is type-specific. As long as you do not have _too many_ such cases, I think that a bit of repetition is fine!

Comment: I've worked a bit more with the concept and it provides me exactly what I need. An immutable type that behaves like a DU but cannot be instantiated without validation. Of course you lose some of the DU advantages, like compilation into table lookup IL code, but for some particular use cases it appears to be very practical. Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well, shortly: you don't hide your options. You just ensure there are enough of them. And you provide functions of proper singnatures to map types.

Now, longer version:
Single responsibility (TM) applies here as well. A concrete union type **must be** dedicated to a concrete problem. In your case it seems reasonable to have `type VerificationStamp = Verified ... | NotYetVerified | YOU_SHALL_NOT_PASS` options. And you don't hide them: there is no good reason for it. Then, you define your `verify` function as well as others you would like to provide to clients of your code. Here is the place you keep things right: by bounding your functions to a reasonable types; as an examply, `verify` would definitely take raw `string` rather than one wrapped into container; but it would return `VerificationStamp "myUrl"`.